# Evaluate $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^8 (-1)^r \binom{20}{r} \binom{20}{8-r}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Please help me with this question
$$\sum_{r=0}^8 (-1)^r \binom{20}{r} \binom{20}{8-r}$$

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a finite sum, why not just compute it?

Comment: Or do you want a more general formula?  There is one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Evaluate
> $$\sum_{r=0}^8 (-1)^r \binom{20}{r} \binom{20}{8-r}$$

I would evaluate $$\sum_{r=0}^8 (-1)^r \binom{20}{r} \binom{20}{12+r}={20\choose 16}$$

that is the coefficient of $x^8$ in the binomial series of $(x^2-1)^{20}$ got by multiplying the binomial series below.
\begin{align*}
(1+x)^{20}&=\sum_{i=0}^{20}{20\choose k}x^i\\
(x-1)^{20}&=\sum_{j=0}^{20}(-1)^j{20\choose j}x^{20-j}\\
\end{align*}